# Spawning enough game objects between two points

Tags: godot

I am trying to spawn enough gameobjects (`ropePieces`) between two point sort of like a rope.
But I don't know how to stop when I reach the end point

```
extends Node

onready var rb=$RigidBody2D
onready var start=$StaticBody2D
onready var end=$StaticBody2D2
var piece= preload("res://scenes/RopePiece.tscn")

var isStop=false
onready var obj2=$StaticBody2D


func _ready():
    for n in 5:
        var obj=piece.instance()
        add_child(obj)
        obj.position=obj2.position
        obj.position.y+=30
        
        obj.get_node("PinJoint2D").node_a=obj2.get_node(".").get_path()
        obj.get_node("PinJoint2D").node_b=obj.get_node(".").get_path()
        obj2=obj
        var distance=obj2.position-obj.position
        print(distance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that you are advancing 30 pixels per object:

```
obj.position.y+=30
```

If that is the space one object ought to take, and you can divide the total distance by 30 and that should give you the number of objects. Something like this:

```
var total = ceil(start.position.distance_to(end.position) / 30)
```

Then use that to iterate (`for n in total: #…`).